# Rank A List Of Values (Largest to Smallest) Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, ranking

I have a VBA code to return a Crew ID for a job completed, the total number of jobs that crew did, how many days that crew was working, and then return the average number of jobs per day. They are in no particular order and all of these categories are adjacent to each other in the excel spreadsheet. In a column next to these other categories, I want to write a VBA code to assign each row a value (1 to 10, since there are 10 crews) based on who has the highest number of jobs per day.

I have looked at other code and suggestions but all I can find is sorting. I don't want to sort them since I can easily do that in Excel and if I sort the values in VBA for that specific column, they will not line up with the rest of the information about them. Any suggestions on how I can "rank" these columns by printing the numbers 1 through 10 in the column adjacent based on who has the highest to lowest jobs per day average?

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: How do you want to handle **ties** ??

Comment: you can sort a range based on a column, multi columns actually, and keep the data relevant to each respective row intact.  I am sure you can "rank them in place instead" if you wish, by running a comparison function.  I am just not sure why you are against sort, you can sort, rank, and then return it to the way it was in a the blink of an eye.

Comment: I demonstrated one example of sorting that would be extremely fast for you below, you probably don't need a multi line sort if you are going off one attribute like avg days.  If you want to write a sub to rank in place we can do that, but I guarantee it will be longer.  You can also create a pivot that will show you the top 10 or top # you specify and leave the data in place.  Many ways to "skin the cat" here.

Comment: I'm not necessarily "against" sort. I am an intern who is still learning how to utilize VBA for these tasks so that is why I need them in that form. In the real world I want the fastest and easiest and most efficient way to give me the results I need. For the purpose of this exercise however I need to utilize VBA. I am going to view your answer below and see if it clarified the issue for me. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can use the [WorksheetFunction.Rank Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-rank-method-excel).  `Rank()` can be used either in the Worksheet or in VBA code.  If you have problems implementing it, post some code and I will be happy to help.

Comment: I ended up doing something like that ^^^ , I "cheated" my way around it using the Record Macro function, turns out that's what my supervisor wanted me to do. Ha! But upon doing that it used a function very similar to what you listed. Another thing I looked at using was a Bubble Sort for anyone else curious on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ripped this code out of Accounting Accrual - Invoicing true up Excel Application, it is one of many sorts on a data "field".

You can do something similar.  To make this more clear for you to apply:
wsBuild is a named sheet (in developer, you can call it directly regardless of worksheet name or position). "twb" just indicates that it is working in thisworkbook, as I am consolidating data from several workbooks (data exports, 3 in this case).

twbNameCol is the col number for the vendor name found in a different function

twbJobNumberCol is the col number for the sales order found in a different function

twbTot1Col is the col number for the sales amount found in a different function

If you want to find the headers dynamically just choose a number higher than your import template in a manner like this, this one accommodates for having 2 total column headers one for accrual and one for invoices, you may not to need to do something like this, since I export from a system I know the header names, or you can make your own, diff accrual is the last column I am looking to find the position on so I break the loop at that point:

```
twbTot1Col = 0
twbTot2Col = 0
'First let's define the column positions
    For j = 1 To 50
        If InStr(wsBuild.Cells(1, j), "Totals") > 0 And twbTot1Col = twbTot2Col Then
            'It is the first time
            twbTot1Col = j
        ElseIf InStr(wsBuild.Cells(1, j), "Totals") > 0 And twbTot1Col <> twbTot2Col Then
            twbTot2Col = j
        ElseIf InStr(wsBuild.Cells(1, j), "JobNumber") > 0 Then
            twbJobNumCol = j
        ElseIf InStr(wsBuild.Cells(1, j), "New VAP") > 0 Then
            twbNewVAPCol = j
        ElseIf InStr(wsBuild.Cells(1, j), "New AP") > 0 Then
            twbNewAPCol = j
        ElseIf InStr(wsBuild.Cells(1, j), "Name") > 0 Then
            twbNameCol = j
        ElseIf InStr(wsBuild.Cells(1, j), "Diff Accrual") > 0 Then
            twbDiffCol = j
            j = 100 'Break loop
        Else
            'Do nothing
        End If
    Next j
```

twbLastRow is the last row in the data range (data range is 2 to LastRow)

It is found like this:

```
twbLastRow = wsBuild.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Here is an example of the sort code, there are some column insertion steps prior to this 1, 2, 3, so I only copied the sort

```
With wsBuild
'4) Perform 3 line sort
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range(.Cells(2, twbNameCol), .Cells(twbLastRow, twbNameCol)), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range(.Cells(2, twbJobNumCol), .Cells(twbLastRow, twbJobNumCol)), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range(.Cells(2, twbTot1Col), .Cells(twbLastRow, twbTot1Col)), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal


         .Sort.SetRange .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(twbLastRow, twbDiffCol + 2))
         .Sort.Header = xlYes
         .Sort.MatchCase = False
         .Sort.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
         .Sort.SortMethod = xlPinYin
         .Sort.Apply
    End With
```

If you take a look at this, you can "rank" your data in any which way you would like.  This sort is **1. vendor** then **2. job number** then **3. accrual amount** then the funs begins to match up invoice import against the accruals.  If you define your sort range properly you will not lose or mismtach any data in adjacent columns.  I guess I am lobbying for you to use sort.

If you provide some code the answer could actually be a sort of your data, insert a rank column, put the ranks in, then unsort your data back to the way it was.  Rather than running a function to "rank" based on a specific attribute (longer ..... but doable).  Cheers, WWC

Comment: Obviously I have left some code out, please don't blast me for the line not being "With wsBuild.Sort" as other methods were also used in that block such as .Range and .Cells  - WWC

Comment: Thank you for that long and comprehensive response. Like I said I am still very much a beginner but I understand the concepts of what you're doing, which is all I can ask for at this point.