# filter and count matches between 3 columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with 13 columns with variable data and I need to filter by this:
date, lot number, line, operator and order number.
The table look something like this way:

```
DATE         QUANTITY  LOT NUMBER    LINE      OPERATOR    ORDER NUM.    WAREHOUSE    
may/12 10:05    423     8765432      first       juan          924324         1    
may/12 10:07    377     76543342     first       james         6435235        1    
may/12 10:05    123     543563       second      juan          924324         1    
may/12 10:06    214     523535235    third       jack          54353          1
```

I need to select and copy in another column (Z by example) the number of times that an operator attend to a different orders and to which line, which order number and date (but I can skip the hour)

The information is always variable but I need to filter firstable by order number.

any idea?
thank you.

---

I used this macro:

```
Sub dOrders()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim x As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim last As Long
Dim sht As String
    sht = ActiveSheet.Name
    last = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    
Set rng = Sheets(sht).Range("A1:N" & last)

Sheets(sht).Range("J2:J" & last).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("V1"), Unique:=True
For Each x In Range([V2], Cells(Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp))

With rng
.AutoFilter
.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=x.Value


  .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
     'Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = x.Value
       'ActiveSheet.Paste
```

**'I comment this because I want it to be pasted in the same sheet like filtre my table and just paste the filter data in the X column to see HOW MANY ORDERS the operator did by date**

```
End With
    Next x

Sheets(sht).AutoFilterMode = False

With Application
.CutCopyMode = False
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

---

And, I also use this macro to count:

```
Sub QuantityOf()
'Finds the last non-blank cell in a single row or column

Dim lrow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 22).End(xlUp).Row

    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    'lCol = Cells(, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    MsgBox "The number is: " & lrow & " -1 " & vbNewLine

End Sub
```

Comment: Suggest you try to record a macro while performing your filter actions, see [How to Record a Macro](http://www.contextures.com/excel-macro-record-test.html), after you have code clean it up and if/when you encounter a problem, ask a specific question concerning the problem.

Comment: @gmalc I changed my question

Comment: @urdearboy I changed my question

Comment: You could leave your data in place, add macros or a trigger (buttons) to sort the way you want or to remove the sorts.  It is a one line sort the way you describe it, but you could always sort by another field once you have it sorted by order#.  You could always sort, copy, paste, remove the sort if you want new formatted tables of data.

Comment: @wookies-will-code I know that I can do that, but I don't know how to. thank you anyway

Comment: Set up a smaller "dummy set" of data as it looks in your sheet, then a "dummy set" of what you want it to look like.  What you are talking about is sorting there is help here for that. Here is some sorting in another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50493095/8716187